# WinAPI client area not being redrawn after SetWindowPos()

Tags: winapi, resize, redraw

I am trying to resize the window of another application (an ipoker client window), using this code:

```
SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, x, y, width, height, SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Now this resizes the window properly, but the client area is not getting redrawn (meaning its just clipped to fit the new window area). This is how it should look:
[how the window looks properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFAnp.jpg)
But this is how it actually looks: [client area is just being clipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMpxJ.jpg)

So I've inspected the messages the window receives upon resizing it by mouse (which works fine) with Spy++ and tried to just send all of them to the window using SendMessage(..), but without any luck as well.

```
WINDOWPOS wpos;
wpos.hwnd = hWnd;
wpos.x = x;
wpos.y = y;
wpos.cx = nWidth;
wpos.cy = nHeight;
wpos.flags = SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | 1000;

NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS params;
params.lppos = &wpos;
params.rgrc[0] = { x, y, width, height};
params.rgrc[1] = rcWindow; // rect of the window before resize
params.rgrc[2] = rcClient; // rect of the client before resize

SendMessage(hWnd, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED, 0, LPARAM(&wpos));

wpos.flags = SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE;
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SIZE, SIZE_RESTORED, MAKELPARAM(nWidth, nHeight));
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, 0, LPARAM(&wpos));

wpos.flags = SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | 1800;
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_NCCALCSIZE, WPARAM(TRUE), LPARAM(&params));
```

Do you have any idea why all of this is not working? Is there no way around subclassing the window (I dont have any experience with that..)? I've also tried to resize the window using placemint (a window positioning tool), but it turns out to have the same problem. The only way to force it to redraw I've found is resize it manually.

Comment: Does a [WM_SETREDRAW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message and/or a `RedrawWindow` call work?

Comment: The fake messages you are throwing at the victim window don't work that way. They are notifications, generated by the system in response to resizing, alongside all necessary internal processing and bookkeeping (which you are skipping). They are meant to inform the application that the geometry of a window changed, in case it needs to perform any custom actions. If `SetWindowPos` doesn't do what you expect, you need to contact the vendor of the application and have them fix it for you.

Comment: Use MoveWindow() instead.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. RedrawWindow, WM_SETREDRAW, InvalidateRect and UpdateWindow all don't help. MoveWindow doesnt work either, same problem. I'm pretty sure I won't get an answer from the vendor, but I might still try it. Is there any other option? Will window subclassing help?

Comment: Why would subclassing help? It just allows you to handle messages that the application apparently doesn't care to handle. It's not going to change anything. You could just as well propose to use multi-threading. Or hooks. Those always come up as potential solutions from developers, that haven't understood what their problem really is.

Comment: Ah, another programmer who wants to cheat at online poker. Sigh.

Comment: I thought about not mentioning online poker because I knew someone would think I would try to cheat...how do you think resizing a window would help me to cheat? Anyway..you're right I havent really understood what my problem is, which is the reason why I posted here in the first place. I hoped someone could point out the possible reasons why this is happening..

Comment: The problem is, that the application doesn't follow the rules. Maybe it implements resizing by handling [WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645620.aspx) and relatives. Or it uses some cheap framework, that installs a mouse hook to handle resizing. Poker is a business where everyone seems to see easy profit, and the crap just keeps piling up from there. If `SetWindowPos` doesn't do what it should, there's nothing you can do apart from contacting the vendor and kindly ask them to hire developers, instead of outsourcing this to Helplessania.

Comment: Damn..okay. I've contacted them, although I dont think they will answer me. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: the size of the canvas (and position of controls if any) are hard coded , you can't do any thing in such situations.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I know of http://hirokuscript.com/ that makes exactly what you are looking for and it works! If you have any clue I will be more than happy if you can share it with me!